# How to insert column at the beginning of file initialized to the same value? awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a tab delimited table that looks like this:

```
col1 col2
t y
g h
g k
j o
```

I'm looking to insert a column at the beginning of the file called "ID" and also initialize all the values in the column to 0. So the final file looks like this:

```
ID col1 col2
0 t y
0 g h
0 g k
0 j o
```

What I have so far.. (which is nowhere near what I need)

```
awk -F$"\t" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print $0,"ID"}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, all you need is:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print (NR>1?0:"ID"), $0}' file.txt
ID      col1    col2
0       t       y
0       g       h
0       g       k
0       j       o
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert a new column (e.g. an ID) before the first column, you can do this:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{$1=++i FS $1;}1' OFS='\t' file.txt
1 First
2 Second
3 Third
4 Fourth
5 Fifth
```

This way you won't need to initialize it to zero, if that's not what you actually want to do.

Comment: no need for the `$'\t'` bashism, awk understands `'\t'` just fine, see how you are using it to set OFS. When 2 variables must have the same value, set them in the same place to that value, not at opposite ends of the script. `i` has the same value as `NR` and so is redundant. You don't need a trailing semi-colon. Changing the value of `$1` causes awk to recompile each record and so is needlessly inefficient.

Comment: Also it requires single quotes for ansi strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a column with all its value set to `0` ,use following:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN{print "ID\tcol1\tcol2"} NR>1{print "0",$1,$2}' inputfile
ID      col1    col2
0       t       y
0       g       h
0       g       k
0       j       o
```

However,if you want to have actual line number/record number in column one ,use following:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN{print "ID\tcol1\tcol2"}NR>1{print (NR-1),$1,$2}' inputfile
ID      col1    col2
1       t       y
2       g       h
3       g       k
4       j       o
```

Comment: Why hard-code col1 and col2 when they're already present in the input file? Why print $1 and $2 instead of $0? You're unnecessarily coupling your code to the input data.

Answer (score 0):

A sed solution:

```
sed -e '1s/^/ID  /' -e '2,$s/^/0      /' file.txt
```

It inserts the column header and tab into line one and inserts 0 and tab at the front of every other line.

To type a tab into your command, hit Control-v first then the tab key.

Answer (score 0):

In awk using conditional operator:

```
$ awk '{ $1 = (NR==1?"ID":0) OFS $1 } 1' file
ID col1 col2
0 t y
0 g h
0 g k
0 j o
```

If you use `OFS` as the separator in code you can control it with `-v OFS='\t'` in output:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{ $1 = (NR==1?"ID":0) OFS $1 } 1' file
ID      col1    col2
0       t       y
0       g       h
0       g       k
0       j       o
```

Comment: That will mess up his fields if any contain blank chars and changing the value of `$1` causes awk to recompile each record and so is needlessly inefficient.